# Export custom formatted expressions from Mathematica

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica, fortran77

How can I get Mathematica to export/save/write a text file with proper Fortan77 formatting, that is, 72 columns and a continuation marker on the sixth column?

I am using Mathematica to generate large and complex analytic expressions, which I then need to insert into pre-existing Fortran77 code. I have everything working correctly in the front end of Mathematica with `FortranForm[]` and

`SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth -> 72]`

However, I can't figure out how to get Mathematica to output correctly to a text file. I want something like this:

```
MM11 = mH1**2 + (g2**2*v1**2)/2. - 
     -  (g2**2*(v1**2/2. - 
     -       ((v2*Cos(phi2) - (0,1)*v2*Sin(phi2))*
     -          (v2*Cos(phi2) + (0,1)*v2*Sin(phi2)))/2.))/2.
...
```

but get either this:

```
MM11 = FortranForm[mH1^2 + (g2^2*v1^2)/2 - ...
```

or this:

```
MM11 = mH1**2 + (g2**2*v1**2)/2. - (g2**2*
 (v1**2/2. - ((v2*Cos(phi2) - (0,1)*v2*Sin(phi2))*
...
```

Comment: I changed the title of the question to be more general, since the answer solves the more general problem of custom output formatting in Mathematica.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a job for the surprisingly little-known `Splice` function. First, you make a template file, with the extension `".mf"`, like so:

```
file = "test.mf";

out = OpenWrite[file];

WriteString[out, "MH1 = <* form *>"];

Close[out];
```

Now when you use `Splice`, Mathematica will automatically replace everything between the `<*` and `*>` delimiters with its evaluated form. So if you set

```
form = 4 + b9^2 + c1^5 + c4^5 + h10^4 + j2 + k10^4 + p10^4 + q5^5 + 
       q8 + s3^3 + s7^2 + t6^3 + u3^2 + u9^3 + x8^4 + z2^3;
```

and call

```
Splice["test.mf", PageWidth -> 72];
```

which will automatically infer you want `FortranForm` output from the file extension, and which allows you to set `PageWidth` as an option, you will get a pretty decent result in the automatically generated file `"test.f"` (note the new extension):

```
MH1 =         4 + b9**2 + c1**5 + c4**5 + h10**4 + j2 + k10**4 + p10**4 + 
    -  q5**5 + q8 + s3**3 + s7**2 + t6**3 + u3**2 + u9**3 + x8**4 + 
    -  z2**3
```

Look at the docs for [`Splice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Splice.html) for more options (changing the name of the output file and the like).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I hadn't thought of trying out Splice. Now I just need to do some dynamic generation of the test.mf file (as e.g. in the Splice help page) and I'm done.

Comment: Pillsy, I've used `Splice` to generate exhaustive test cases for some mathematical s/w I was writing. Very useful, but occasionally tricky to get Mathematica to produce correct output.