# Formatting numbers when writing to files in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, precision

This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4943706/181759) question regarding number formatting, and related to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687705/181759) about obtaining very specific Mathematica output to text files.

I frequently have to use high precision in Mathematica for data generation but only need relatively low precision for visualization purposes. I also want to store the data for later use with all Symbol names and Array structures intact. For this I have been using `Save[]`, but there are two related problems.

1. The high precision "pollutes" my results with superfluous digits which are very hard to get rid of:

   ```
   In[1]  := b = SetPrecision[7, 50]; a = Pi/b
   Out[1] := 0.44879895051282760549466334046850041202816705705358654585356351318683091518373`50.
   In[2]  := InputForm @ N[a, 6]
   Out[2] := 0.44879895051282760549466334046850041203`6.
   ```

   where I really only need 0.448799.
2. Sometimes even the number indicating precision is corrupted and I get values like `4.72642364528438598726943'5.9999999999999999999999` where I don't generally need the precision and `4.72642` would suffice.

Both of these introduce significant overhead to the file size, and while hard disk storage is cheap, file size makes a huge difference when later loading the files back into Mathematica.

So, starting with, e.g., `aa` that contains 50 digit arbitrary precision numbers in an irregular array, is there a built in way for me to get a text file that would read something like this

```
aa = {{2.0437`4, 4.7276`4, ...}, ...}
```

**EDIT**: To clarify, I am not having problems with the display of numbers or with tracking the precision of numbers or with changing the precision of numbers. What I am having trouble with is controlling how a number is written to a file.

Using `N`, `NumberForm`, `OutputForm`, `InputForm`, `*Form`, etc, all do not work properly with `Save`. And `Save` is the only exporting option I can find that exports the symbol and array structure. `Export` and `Put*` can be used to control the formatting better but they don't include the symbol (and in the case of `Export` the array structure is lost as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really require things like 2.0437`4, or would the machine double 2.0437 suffice? If the latter then you could do something like

```
N[SetPrecision[values,6]]
```

to coerce to machine doubles that will (mostly) show six decimal digits.

An possible advantage is in reading back it. Your array will now be machine doubles, hence packable. I'm not sure if Get or Import automatically pack, but Developer`ToPackedArray will do that.

**---edit 2011-02-11---**

Now that I've seen what can go wrong...

Here is an example, using your later input and a few others that I hope will be representative.

```
aa = {7.469702041097916467293771347613073888816285869`15.\
  954589770191005*^-51, 5555.22222222222222222223,
  .00000000002222222222222222222222222227777777777777, N[E, 22]^33}
```

First convert to a string. This may actually be all you really want, for purposes of saving to a file. I use NumberForm, but with a custom formatting function (cribbed by and large from documentation pages).

```
In[39]:= 
    InputForm[ToString[
      NumberForm[N[aa], 6, 
       NumberFormat :> (If[#3 != "", Row[{#1, "*^", #3}], #1] &)]]]

Out[39]//InputForm=
"{7.4697*^-51, 5555.22, 2.22222*^-11, 2.14644*^14}"
```

Notice that the expression conversion works fine on this.

```
In[40]:=
    InputForm[ToExpression[
      ToString[NumberForm[N[aa], 6, 
       NumberFormat :> (If[#3 != "", Row[{#1, "*^", #3}], #1] &)]]]]

Out[40]//InputForm=
{7.4697*^-51, 5555.22, 2.22222*^-11, 2.14644*^14}
```

**---end edit---**

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: I don't require the precision information but I just find it extremely difficult to remove :-). My problem is not with how many digits are shown in a notebook, my problem is with how many digits are written into a file, preferably a plain text file at that.

Comment: Try ToExpression[ToString[NumberForm[<list of numbers>, 6]]] to get six digits printed in your file. Can use Save or Put depending on specifics of what you need.

Comment: Doesn't work if the numbers are floats. I'm working on a kludge that does something similar to what you're suggesting but with `RealDigits` and `FromDigits`.

Comment: very nice. About 20% faster then my kludge, and probably the best solution barring some specific feature in mma9.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very kludgy way of doing what I want, i.e., forcing Mathematica to discard superfluous digits.

```
aa =  {7.469702041097916467293771347613073888816285869`15.954589770191005*^-51, ...};
list = RealDigits[N[aa, 6]];
bb = Thread @ #1*10.^(#2 - #3) &[FromDigits /@ First /@ list, 
                           Last /@ list, 
                           First /@ Dimensions /@ First /@ list];
InputForm @ bb

{7.469700000000001*^-51, ...}
```

Which is already an improvement but still has more than two times the character count of what is necessary.

EDIT: And we have a winner:

```
list = Transpose @ {FromDigits /@ First /@ #, 
                    Last /@ #, 
                    First /@ Dimensions /@ First /@ #}& @ RealDigits[N[aa, 6]];
bb = ToExpression[ToString[#1] <> ".*^" <> ToString[#2 - #3]] & @@@ list;
InputForm @ bb

{7.4697`*^-51, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OutputForm` is your friend for getting rid of extra digits.  You could hack it into a string, although it is ugly

```
f[x_,n_]:=StringJoin[ToString[OutputForm[N[x,n]]],"`",ToString[Round[Precision[N[x,n]]]]];
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the backticks or precisions, the simple solution is:

```
FormatList[l_,n_]:=OutputForm[N[#,n]]&//@l;
```

Edit: The second solution doesn't seem to work; provisional fix is

```
FormatList[l_,n_]:=OutputForm[N[#,n]&//@l];
```

Comment: I don't want to keep track of the precision, in fact, I want to do the opposite. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Anyway I can not get your example to produce `aa = {{2.0437, 4.7276, ...}, ...}`, instead it gives me `OutputForm` (the style that looks like type writer written formulas with exponents on different lines than the base), Did you have something other in mind and simply miswrote?

Comment: Timo: It was a mistake on my part.  `OutputForm` shouldn't be mapped to all levels, but `N` should be.  Try the following: `OutputForm[N[#,n]&//@l]`.  Fookin' brackets.  (Edited the post as well.)

Note also that this may introduce some small numerical instabilities, as all the subexpressions of these computations will be evaluated as well.  I'll look into a way to figure this out.

Comment: I think my example is too simple ;-), the usefulness of `OutputForm` is limited to numbers without exponents. Try your solution with, e.g., 3.4*^-50.

Comment: Timo: Alright.  Sorry for wasting your time; I keep on forgetting pathological cases.  Looks like you're going to have to go with a more involved solution...

Comment: drvitek: Time is never wasted here on SO! Thanks for the effort, and as you can see, the StringJoin approach was correct in the end, it just needed some NumberFormat magic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a **direct** solution to your problem, but I do have a suggestion that may be helpful in other ways.

If you're interested in saving Mathematica session state and definitions, you're often better off using [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html) as opposed to `Save`. You get some sort of binary image instead of a plain text file, and not only does it typically use much less space, they load much, much, much faster. The main drawback is the resulting files aren't at all portable between versions of Mathematica, or different OSes, or anything like that, and they obviously aren't human readable.

You can also suppress the backticks and precision by using the [`NumberMarks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberMarks.html) option with `InputForm` et al. If you're actually interested in reducing the precision, I think using `N` is the way to go.

Comment: DumpSave is fine, if you're not going to distribute the data to other people/systems.  For example, OS X machines can't read the files created by Windows or Linux, and 64-bit Windows can't read the files created by 32-bit Windows (and vice versa.)  In general version N+1 should be able to read files from from version N (assuming you're on the same OS and bitness) but version N might not be able to read N+1.

Comment: A binary image is sadly not acceptable. I may have to import data later into other programs.